# Select nested list with LINQ query from many to many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, many-to-many

I have created database for survey where questions and answers are stored in database. Here i created table for surveys (i have 3 types of survey). It contains SurveyID, SurveyName. Another table is Questions and it contains QuestionId, QuestionText. Next table is Answers and it has AnswerId and AnswerText. Different surveys may have same questions. So i created table SurveysQuestions for many to many relationship. Another table is SurveysQuestionsAnswers table it has SurveyId, QuestionId, AnswerId and it is also many to many relationship. Now i need to select  questions for survey 1 and it should contain list of questions. Each question should have question text and list of answers which belong to this question. I cant write linq query to select like this. I attach my ViewModel and Database design. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCQ1a.jpg)

```
List<SurveyViewModel> list = (from jsqa in db.JSTC_SURVEY_QUESTION_ANSWER
                                      where jsqa.SURVEY_ID == 1
                                      select new SurveyViewModel
                                      {
                                          question = (from jsq in db.JSTC_SURVEY_QUESTION where jsq.QUESTION_ID == jsqa.QUESTION_ID select jsq.QUESTION_TEXT).ToString(),
                                          answers = (from jsa in db.JSTC_SURVEY_ANSWER where jsa.ANSWER_ID == jsqa.ANSWER_ID select jsa.ANSWER_TEXT).ToList()
                                      }).ToList();
```

Comment: Could you outline the approaches you have tried?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro i updated question check the approach